# Изменить вид компонентов при изменении размера фрейма

Tags: c#, winforms

Как при изменении размера фрейма задать другие свойства вида для компонентов? Мне нужно чтобы panel1 которая имеет свойство Dock Left при уменьшении размера фрейма (например при size 1000;500, уменьшить до 500;300 ) изменила свойство Dock на Top. Тоже самое для кнопок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как при изменении размера фрейма..

Речь идет наверно о форме (метки c# и winforms):

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Width<500)
    {
        panel1.Height = 75;
        panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        button1.Location = new Point(50, 5);
    }
    else
    {
        panel1.Width = 75;
        panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        button1.Location = new Point(5, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как вернуть все обратно если вернуть размер формы обратно?

Comment: Там же указано: `else...` , то есть если ширина больше 500, у панели опять `DockStyle.Left` и так далее.